# Importing OBJLoader in NUXT

Tags: vue.js, three.js, nuxt.js

I've write little app on three js, and now i need to load obj and mtl, but i cant find how can i import OBJLoader.js in main .vue file. My example below:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as OBJLoader from '@/plugins/OBJLoader';
import * as MTLLoader from '@/plugins/MTLLoader';
import {TweenMax} from 'gsap';
let OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE);
export default{
    data(){
        return {

        }
    },
    watch: {

    },
    mounted(){
        console.clear();
        //VARIABLES
        let canvas = document.getElementById('myscene');
        let width = window.innerWidth;
        let height = window.innerHeight;
        ...
        var loader_9 = new THREE.OBJLoader(); 
        loader_9.load(

             'Model/Provod.obj',

        function ( object ) {
        scene.add( object );
        });
    ...
    };
```

This is NUXT error message:

```
ReferenceError
THREE is not defined
```

and screenshot:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhVXf.png)

how should I import OBJLoader and other loaders for three js in nuxt?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Where are you importing THREE from? Is it another plugin or a package you installed and added to nuxt.config?

Comment: installed with npm